# My Kali linux showing 'No module named importlib' 'from importlib import import_module'

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, kali-linux

Trying to install build dependencies with pip which is installing in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
As I try to install proceed gives an error

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Cloning https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue to /tmp/pip-req-build-VQbxfT
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue /tmp/pip-req-build-VQbxfT
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpNlNAvr                            
       cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-VQbxfT                                                                                                                                  
  Complete output (4 lines):                                                                                                                                           
  Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                   
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 16, in <module>                                                                    
      from importlib import import_module                                                                                                                              
  ImportError: No module named importlib                                                                                                                               
  ----------------------------------------                                                                                                                             
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpNlNAvr Check the logs for full command output.
```

so I try to install importlib with pip and I still get the same error. Then I install it directly to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/ using

```
pip install importlib --target=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/
```

because pip has been installing all packages to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages,
but I still get the error either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to install `python-netfilterqueue`.

You can visit github page and see this

> The current version of NetfilterQueue requires Python 3.6 or later.

So you can't install this lib for python 2.7

But you can install `0.9.0` as it also stated that

> The last version with support for Python 2.7 was 0.9.0.

```
pip install NetfilterQueue=0.9.0
```

Comment: I'm entirely trying to get mitmf working which is based entirely on python2

Comment: try `pip install NetfilterQueue=0.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to python3 because this will definitely work.

First you have to install cython.

```
pip install cython
```

Then after that you need to make sure you install NetfilterQueue from source.

```
git clone https://github.com/oremanj/python-netfilterqueue
```

Navigate to the netfilterqueue directory.

```
cd python-netfilterqueue
```

Then run this command.

```
python3 setup.py install
```

That's it. It should work properly

Comment: try to give some additional information on one liner answers